# playframework, how to do a combobox where it modifies the JPA bean for me?

Tags: playframework

We have:

```
public class TicketDbo {
   @Required
   @ManyToOne
   public ProjectDbo project;
}
```

We then have many projects to choose from, so we add a pulldown menu when you edit the Ticket where you can choose one of the projects.

We want to render something like this(this is the easy part and we know how to do this part with `#{select}`:

```
<select ... >
  <option value="" selected="selected">Please select...</option>
  <option value="1">Project1</option> 
  <option value="56">Project2</option>
</select>
```

NOTE: The value above is the entity id in the database.

What we want is some piece of code outside the controller where this code would run before the controller is invoked (AND we could hopefully re-use this code for any of these *ManyToOne* situations that happen all the time):

```
 ProjectDbo project = JPA.em().getReference(selectedOptionValueFromAbove); 
 //note, getReference doesn't hit DB!!!!
 ticketDbo.setProject(project);
```

Then our controller would be the same as always:

```
public static void postTicket(TicketDbo ticket) {
    //at this point the ticket already has the ProjectDbo and validation of it being required has already been run from the @Required annotation
}
```

Anyone knows how to do something like this? Or is there a plugin to help with this?

@2ND QUESTION: How do this with an enumeration as well?  (Hopefully that is just a tweak to the above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work well(formed from one of the comments @maartencls made on another answer)

```
@Global
public class ProjectRefBinder implements TypeBinder<ProjectDBO>{
    @Override
    public Object bind(String name, Annotation[] annotations, String value,
            Class actualClass, Type genericType) throws Exception {
        if(value == null)
            return null;
        EntityManager em = JPA.em();
        Long id = Long.valueOf(value);
        ProjectDBO ref = em.getReference(ProjectDBO.class, id);
        return ref;
    }
}
```

Then in the page, I can do a #{ticket.project} and in my controller method, my TicketDbo ends up with a ProjectDbo proxy wrapping the id selected!!!  works great so far I think.  This class also works not just for my TicketDbo for other entities as well that have a ProjectDbo in them.

Comment: related but not the same post is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238366/any-playframework-dynamic-combobox-pulldown-menu-examples-out-there

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do what you want, as far as I'm aware, is to use the cache. Create a job that:

- Retrieves a list of projects in the database
- Stores each project in the cache using a known key, like "ProjectCached_X" where X is the id

The job may run as often as you expect your projects to change.

Then you can create a method that checks the cache for `"ProjectCached_"+ selectedId` and retrieves it.

The system has several issues:
 - The project may be out of the cache, you'll need to go back to the database to retrieve it in that scenario.
 - You risk working with stale data (a removed project) and will only see that in the commit when the rel fails

Retrieving the project by Id shouldn't be a big deal, but... your call :)

**Edit on comment**
Sorry but I got confused by your requirement of having a method load the object before calling the controller. If you want that method, the way to work is with cache.

For the controller method, you mention you only want one parameter. That's in fact the only thing you need. If you name your select properly (object.field), Play will automatically link the provided *id* with the object. Or it should.

Comment: why would I need a cache when I can use entityMgr.getReference(id) which does not hit the database, so you may be onto something if I can get more detail on how I get playframework to actually get that reference and stuff the selected one into the TicketDbo

Comment: ie. your solution implies that it violates my actual question in that the method signature would be postTicket(TicketDbo ticket, Long selectedId) which is not what I want since I would end up with about 6 parameters doing it that way....I just want a TicketDbo passed in.

Comment: The section on [POJO object binding of the controller docs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/controllers#anamepojoPOJOobjectbindinga) might help.

Comment: binding id is not enough...hibernate needs an entity created by hibernate through getReference or find or even merge to merge the entity back in before I can use it to save the TicketDbo object that was changed......@maartencis...you may be on to something there! I didn't notice the custom bindings and maybe I can use JPA.em() there...might work I think.

Comment: I've been trying to make this work with custom bindings, but couldn't. Apparently `JPAPlugin` overrides these and it kept on throwing errors... And Play does seem to load the entire model when you just rely on the normal object/jpa binding.

Comment: I might have the solution based on @maartencis post as I have been playing with that and I think I got it working but need to check more before I post that solution.

Comment: If you check the [next section](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/controllers#objectbinding) from link @maartencls posted, the playframework before binding, will load any db object the is referenced. Enable hibernate logging to verify. That is actually a common practice when updating children objects.

Comment: @Pere hmmm, I can't seem to give the other 25 bounty points to you...that kind of sucks...very weird.

Comment: @mericano1 you need to reread the question.  I can do a simple passing a User into a method already.  We are trying to bind another JPA object inside that User object!!! and there was no example of that.

Comment: Dean I understand, maybe it wasn't clear what I was trying to say. In your code, the comment says "//note, getReference doesn't hit DB!!!!" . What I was trying to make clear is that the playframework binder **does hit** the db. That's all

Comment: @DeanHiller probably because bounty expired. If it expires without you assigning it, only half the points are awarded, the rest is lost. But it's ok, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

With enumeration, association is automatic, just use the select tag

```
#{select 'object.enumField', items: EnumSet.allOf(enums.MyEnum.class), value: object.enumField /}
```

You can also use 'labelProperty' if you want to display something else than the enum name.

With this, your enum value will be automatically associated with your field

I guess, with dependent objects, it is the same as far as you bind your select to "ticket.project.id" but I never tried this. You may just have to call merge in your controller after but as Play does some special things with JPA objects on binding this may not work

Comment: yes, I am mainly trying to solve the dependent objects first.....enums is probably easy after that and your enum solution is  good.

Comment: and this worked a little better for i18n stuff (for enums only)... #{select field.name, items: EnumSet.allOf(models.EntityStatus.class), value: field.value, valueProperty:'code', labelProperty:'guiLabel' /}

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the code in the [@Before](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/controllers#before). The code is guaranteed to run before the Controller action method is invoked.